# ML Binary Classifier - Probability of getting result by chance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability

If I have a trained binary classifier, what is the probability of making a correct prediction by chance?

For example, lets say that I want to make 5 predictions. What is the probability of getting all 5 predictions correct by chance?

Is it: 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 * 0.5 = 0.0313 ?

Comment: if the classes are equally probable then yes. If one class is more probable (common) then it depends how do you "guess", but the general property is the same - this probability will be extremely small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, however, under the assumption that classes are equally probable.

As a similar thought experiment, if you have a model with 99% accuracy (meaning that for any, randomly chosen sample, it will provide correct label 99% of the time), it also does not have high probability of having **all** samples correctly. For 100 samples it is just about 36%, and for 300 it is less than 5%... for 1000 it is 0.004%.

In general probability of many event happening one by one will fall down very quickly (exponentially) if the probability of each success is constant.